# Wordpress shortecode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am using myCred on my site. Specially myCred transfer. There is an existing shortcode for this particular plugin.
[mycred_transfer pay_to=1]
where pay_to is the recipient wordpress user id. I can only manually add a user id. But so I need to manually create a shortcode for every created user and it is no go :D.
so therefore I created this function to gather user id of the current post.

```
// Shortcode to output custom PHP
function author_id( $atts ) {
   echo $user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
}
add_shortcode( 'my_author_id', 'author_id');
```

and it works for the user ID. but do not know how to replace it "1" in [mycred_transfer pay_to=1]
because if I replace "1" with a shortcode it does not work.
Thanks for ideas

Comment: _"because if I replace "1" with a shortcode it does not work."_ - Please show us your attempt that doesn't work. Easier to find potential mistakes then :-)

Comment: If I use shortcode in a shortcode like this "[mycred_transfer pay_to=[my_author_id]]" ... it does not work.

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do. You could - if you're using your shortcode in a template do somthing like  `echo do_shortcode('[mycred_transfer pay_to='.get_current_user_id().`]);` But you can't put a shortcode argument into a shortcode like you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @HowardE but I get error with this code `function author_id( $atts ) 
{ 
echo do_shortcode('[mycred_transfer pay_to='.get_current_user_id().]);
}
add_shortcode( 'my_author_id', 'author_id');`

Comment: Yes... Of course you do. I told you why.